# Search substring in multi value field

Tags: solr

I have field like below (result of query)

```
"bestseller_archive_position": [
      "2015-11-13_1",
      "2015-11-12_2"
    ],
```

Now I need to find documents that contain string "2015-11-13" in this field. But when I do

```
q=2015-11-13
```

or

```
q=2015-11-13*
```

I receive 0 dcuments. I've tested different field types. How can I perform such search ?

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to guess with such few information. However, shooting in the dark, I bet you're using a request handler with a "lucene" query parser, that means the - has a precise meaning (prohibited clause, NOT). So you should escape those special chars with a leading \

On top of that, enable debug (add a debug=true) and you will see how Solr "sees" the query that is executed.

Comment: thank you I will check that. If I'll have move questions I'LL write more info

Answer (score 0):

First you should proper configure a field type for search. For your purposes the String type will be good, it will store and index data as is. You should put following config in your schema.xml

```
<field name="bestseller_archive_position" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
```

When you search you should also define a field in which you do a search. In other case search will be against default field. E.g.

```
q=bestseller_archive_position:2015-11-13*
```

Comment: unfortunatly it does not work that way. Funny thing is that when I query like this `bestseller_archive_position:2015-11-` then I receive both records that I expect but when I do `bestseller_archive_position:2015-11-1` or `bestseller_archive_position:2015-11-13` than i receive nothing. Wild card does not help

Comment: It seems that you have problem with tokenizer, it spits initial string  `2015-11-13_1` on tokens `2015` `11` `13_1`.  Try to change field definition to
      `<fieldType name="keyword" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>`.